# Reverse json order with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, reverse

I have a json object and i would like to reverse the order.

My json:

```
var json = {
        'car 1' : {
            'brand' : 'Seat',
            'model' : 'Ibiza',
            'equip' : {
                'n1' : 'vidros electricos',
                'n2' : 'fecho central',
                'n3' : 'dirercção assistida'
            }
        },
        'car 2' : {
            'brand' : 'Volkswagen',
            'model' : 'Golf',
            'equip' : {
                'n1' : 'vidros electricos',
                'n2' : 'fecho central',
                'n3' : 'dirercção assistida',
                'n4' : 'abs'
            }
        },
        (...)
    }
```

i've tried with:

```
$.each(json.reverse(), function(index, value) {...}
```

but this gives me an error. How can i do this?

tks in advance.

Comment: May those links help you. 

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702805/reverse-the-json-array-stored-in-javascript-variable

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556539/parse-json-list-in-reverse-order

Comment: you gotta reverse the json as whole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reverse() doesn't work because it is a function of Array, not Object. Convert your object to an array and it should work fine.

```js
   var json = {
    'car 1' : {
 'brand' : 'Seat',
 'model' : 'Ibiza',
 'equip' : {
  'n1' : 'vidros electricos',
  'n2' : 'fecho central',
  'n3' : 'dirercção assistida'
 }
},
'car 2' : {
 'brand' : 'Volkswagen',
 'model' : 'Golf',
 'equip' : {
  'n1' : 'vidros electricos',
  'n2' : 'fecho central',
  'n3' : 'dirercção assistida',
      'n4' : 'abs'
 }
}
};
  
var jsonArr = Object.keys(json).map(function(key) {
    return [key, json[key]];
});
  
jsonArr = jsonArr.reverse();
    
console.log(jsonArr[0]);  // Will print car 2
console.log(jsonArr[1]);  // Will print car 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of properties in objects cannot be reversed because they are not index based. Only arrays can be reversed because they are index based.